# How to fully delete a git repository created with init?

Tags: git, git-init

I created a git repository with `git init`. I'd like to delete it entirely and init a new one.

Answer (score 2072, accepted):

Git keeps all of its files in the `.git` directory. Just remove that one and init again.

If you can't find it, it's because it is hidden.

- In Windows 7, you need to go to your folder, click on <kbd>Organize</kbd> on the top left, then click on <kbd>Folder and search options</kbd>, then click on the <kbd>View</kbd> tab and click on the <kbd>Show hidden files, folders and drives</kbd> radio button.
- On a Mac OS:

  - Open a Terminal (via Spotlight: press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, type `terminal` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and run:

    ```
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles 1 && killall Finder
    ```

    Note: The keyboard shortcut to show hidden files in Finder is 
    <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> so it is no longer necessary to modify the 
    finder config this way
  - You could also type `cd` (the space is important), drag and drop your git repo folder from Finder to the terminal window, press <kbd>return</kbd>, then type `rm -fr .git`, then <kbd>return</kbd> again.
- On Ubuntu, use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>.

Comment: Note: After you have removed the hidden .git file, you should enter `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO && killall Finder` to hide the hidden files once again.

Comment: To show/hide files on macOS (in Finder): `cmd + shift + .` This was a top result on Google for me so people will probably find it a lot even though it's old.

Comment: @Van those are bash flags (options), and they can go in whatever order you'd like :)

Comment: That solution was not enough when I added an iOS project as submodule. It appeared as a red folder with "iOSapp @ 1d12345" that couldn't be accesses nor could I push new changes (it said always it matches master already). I used the answer with "find . -type f | grep -i "\.git" | xargs rm" that removed whatever created the problem and now it works.

Comment: Hi
I just do it accidentally and all my work vanishes.
Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: Cant find this mentioned but if you want to remove the git repository from in windows 10 cmd then use ```rmdir /s .git``` when inside the directory that contains the git repository.

Comment: If you get permission denied while deleting, just rename the .git folder to something else and delete.

Answer (score 1036):

If you really want to remove all of the repository, leaving only the working directory then it should be as simple as this.

```
rm -rf .git
```

The usual provisos about `rm -rf` apply. Make sure you have an up to date backup and are absolutely sure that you're in the right place before running the command. etc., etc.

Comment: And you can use this on Windows too, in git shell

Comment: It repeatedly says it can't: rm: `cannot remove 'Rift/.git/objects/pack': Directory not empty`, and yes I ran rm -rf

Comment: Side note, -rf is two options joined together: -r for recursive removal, -f to force the action

Comment: Hi
I just do it accidentally and all my work vanishes.
Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: @Abdullah Saud No way you could undo it when running that command. The warning should be put earlier.

Comment: For Windows PowerShell users, run
`Remove-Item ".git" -Recurse -Force`

[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3)

Answer (score 72):

If you want to delete all .git folders in a project use the following command:

```
find . -type f | grep -i "\.git" | xargs rm
```

This will also delete all the .git folders and .gitignore files from all subfolders

Comment: This deleted my french.gite.txt

Comment: Had issues with syncing an iOS project as submodule. Just removing .git directory didn't work somehow, this solved it though. Probably some more files hidden in subfolders?

Answer (score 34):

after cloning the repo

```
cd /repo folder/
```

to go to the file directory then

```
ls -a
```

to see all files hidden and unhidden

```
.git .. .gitignore .etc
```

if you like you can check the repo origin

```
git remote -v
```

now delete .git which contains everything about git

```
rm -rf .git
```

after deleting, you would discover that there is no git linked check remote again

```
git remote -v
```

now you can init your repository with

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/Leonuch/flex.git
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213449/68587). All the other steps add nothing to the answer.

Answer (score 16):

Alternative to killing TortoiseGit:

- Open the TortoiseGit-Settings (right click to any folder, TortoiseGit → Settings)
- Go to the **Icon Overlays** option.
- Change the *Status Cache* from **Default** to **None**
- Now you can delete the directory (either with Windows Explorer or `rmdir /S /Q`)
- Set back the *Status Cache* from **None** to **Default** and you should be fine again...

Answer (score 11):

Where $GIT_DIR is the path to the folder to be searched (the git repo path), execute the following in terminal.

```
find $GIT_DIR -name *.git* -ok rm -Rf {} \;
```

This will recursively search for any directories or files containing ".git" in the file/directory name within the specified Git directory. This will include .git/ and .gitignore  files and any other .git-like assets. The command is interactive and will ask before removing. To proceed with the deletion, simply enter y, then Enter.

Answer (score 5):

To fully delete the `.git` repository in your computer (in Windows 8 and above):

1. The `.git` repository is normally hidden in windows
2. So you need  to mark the "hidden items" to show the hidden folders
3. At the top site of you directory you find "view" option
4. Inside "view" option you find "hidden items" and mark it
5. Then you see the `.git` repository then you can delete it

Answer (score 4):

I tried:

`rm -rf .git` and also

> Git keeps all of its files in the .git directory. Just remove that one
>   and init again.

Neither worked for me.  Here's what did:

- Delete all files except for `.git`
- git add . -A
- git commit -m "deleted entire project"
- git push

Then create / restore the project from backup:

- Create new project files (or copy paste a backup)
- git add . -A
- git commit -m "recreated project"
- git push

Answer (score 4):

you can use :

> git remote remove origin

to remove a linked repo then:

> git remote add origin

to add new one

Comment: this will not remove the repo from local computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an **alias** for it. I am using ZSH shell with Oh-my-Zsh and here is an handy alias:

```
# delete and re-init git
# usage: just type 'gdelinit' in a local repository
alias gdelinit="trash .git && git init"
```

I am using [Trash](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash) to trash the `.git` folder since using `rm` is really dangerous:

```
trash .git
```

Then I am re-initializing the git repo:

```
git init
```

Answer (score 2):

No worries, Agreed with the above answers:

But for Private project, please follow the steps for Gitlab:

1. Login to your account
2. Click on Settings -> General
3. Select your Repository (that you wants to delete)
4. Click on 'Advanced' on the bottom-most
5. Click on 'Remove Project'
6. You will be asked to type your project name

   This action can lead to data loss. To prevent accidental actions we ask you to confirm your intention. 
   Please type 'sample_project' to proceed or close this modal to cancel.
7. Now your project is deleted successfully.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows PowerShell users:

```
rm -Recurse -Force .git*
```

This will remove the .git folder, and all the .gitignore, .gitattributes files.

Answer (score 0):

In windows:

1. Press Start Button
2. Search Resource Monitor
3. Under CPU Tab -> type .git -> right click rundll32 and end process

Now you can delete .git folder

Answer (score 0):

**Windows cmd prompt:**
(You could try the below command directly in **windows cmd** if you are not comfortable with **grep, rm -rf, find, xargs etc.,** commands in **git bash** )

Delete ***.git*** recursively inside the project folder by the following command in cmd:

> FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S *.git*') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%G"

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf .git worked for me
I did a
ls -a
to see all hidden files/folders first.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio it could be done from settings:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

true,like mine was stored in USERS,so had to open USERS go to  View on you upper left find Options,open it and edit folders'view options in view still to display hidden files/folders,all your folders will be displayed and you can deleted the repo manually,remember to hide the files/folders once  done with the delete.