# Is there a command to undo git init?

Tags: git, git-init

I just Git init'ed a repos with a wrong user, and want to undo it.  Is there any command for this?  Do I actually have to go in and edit the .git directory?

Comment: [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1213430/6521116)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)

Answer (score 1819, accepted):

You can just delete .git.  Typically:

```
rm -rf .git
```

Then, recreate as the right user.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, but can you expound on "if you just inited it"- what if i've done some stuff since, a few commits etc, would simply removing this be a problem?

Comment: No, you can always just remove the entire `.git` subdirectory with no ill effects.

Comment: @mskfisher: No ill effects besides your repository being gone, that is!

Comment: If you init a sub git directory in your current git directory, don't do the command above.

Comment: I think this does not work in windows. For windows `rmdir /s .git`

Comment: Not working. It says .git\refs\heads - Access is denied.

Comment: @Zen, why not? Say you accidentally initialized your workspace folder with git and all subdirectories are git repos, is there any harm in removing `.git` from the workspace folder?

Comment: This helped me, thank you!  I was looking all over to find the answer to this problem. [This article](https://kolosek.com/git-commands-tutorial-part2/) also helped me to get a better understanding of how git commands work as well.

Comment: Found out that this command must be executed on cmd.exe, not on Powershell. Otherwise you get a `Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.\.git'.` error.

Comment: Cross platform if you have npm: `npx rimraf .git`

Comment: running `git remote remove origin` after this answer worked best for me

Comment: In powershell is ```rm -r -Force .git```

Comment: don't run this command if you accidentally run `git init` on a folder you already git initialized before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397888/how-to-undo-misoperation-of-reinitialized-existing-git-repository

Answer (score 80):

In windows, type `rmdir .git` or `rmdir /s .git` if the .git folder has subfolders.

If your git shell isn't setup with proper administrative rights (i.e. it denies you when you try to `rmdir`), you can open a command prompt (possibly as administrator--hit the windows key, type 'cmd', right click 'command prompt' and select 'run as administrator) and try the same commands.

`rd` is an alternative form of the `rmdir` command. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rmdir.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: rmdir /s .git 
if you already add a remote to force files and subfolders

Comment: I did a git init by accident on a folder in Win7.  The rmdir /s .git removed it.

Comment: confirmed works in `windows10` with `VS code`.  thanks.

Answer (score 15):

remove the `.git` folder in your project root folder

if you installed submodules and want to remove their git, also remove `.git` from submodules folders

Answer (score 13):

In PowerShel this is the way to do it:

```
Remove-Item ".git" -Force -Recurse
```

This is the shell the VSC uses.

Answer (score 9):

Git keeps all of its files in the .git directory. Just remove that one and init again.

This **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213446/6521116)** well show you how to find the hide .git file on Windows, Mac OSX, Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

I'm running Windows 7 with git bash console.
The above commands wouldn't work for me.

So I did it via Windows Explorer.
I checked show hidden files, went to my projects directory and manually deleted the .git folder.
Then back in the command line I checked by running git status.

Which returned...

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Which is exactly the result I wanted.  It returned that the directory is not a git repository (anymore!).