# How to undo git init on a home directory?

Tags: git

I did `git init` and `git add .` on my home directory, which slowed every operation down, I think, because the directory is so large. How can I undo `git init` of the home directory?

Comment: [Is there a way to undo git init](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3212459/6521116)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a command to undo git init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212459/is-there-a-command-to-undo-git-init)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can just do `rm -rf $HOME/.git` to remove all the version control information stored by git, which undoes whatever `git init` did.

But I highly doubt that running `git init` could slow anything down.

Comment: If he's running on Windows perhaps he's got some shell extension trying to badge everything now.