# Deleting git from home directory (Using Terminal/Command Line)

Tags: git, command-line, terminal

Somehow I must have initiated a git at my home directory because now when I type 'git status,' I'm getting a whole list of of 'untracked files' which include my personal folders for my computer that have nothing to do with Github (Pictures, Downloads, Documents, Desktop, etc...).

When I type `ls -a` at my 'root' (for me, it's at `/Users/(my name)`), I am seeing `.git` which means I have a git directory here and am not supposed to.  I found a related question on stack overflow below - my follow up to this question is, since I have folders within my home drive that *are* legitimate git repos and that I *do* want to keep, I want to make sure I'm not deleting those with the recursive `rm`.

I am a super newbie, so it's difficult for me to know what I should even be searching for.  I've spent a few hours on this already with little progress. Another possible solution I've found is to add my home drive to gitignore, but it would be even better if I could completely remove the '.git' from my home folder completely.

Related: [How to undo git init on a home directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193565/how-to-undo-git-init-on-a-home-directory/15193576#15193576)

Comment: It looks like you already found your answer, and just needed some reassurance. Good on ya!

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the `.git` folder from your home directory.

`rm -rf ~/.git` will only remove the `.git` folder that lives directly within your home folder. It will not touch any other git repositories you may have in other locations within your home folder.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried `rm -rf .git` a few times when I was at my root directory  (`User/(my name)`) which did not work, so I'm not sure what difference the tilde in front would do.  Eventually I was able to delete the contents inside the `.git` folder using the extremely technical method of opening it in a Finder window.  Thank you though - I will try if it happens again!

Comment: it worked on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf ~/.git` is the command that I used on a mac computer and it did work.