# My whole laptop is an untracked file in git

Tags: git, github

Dunno what happened, but I get this when I open a new project in my Code VS.

[image]

How do I remove this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo git init on a home directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193565/how-to-undo-git-init-on-a-home-directory)

Comment: Warning to anyone in a similar situation with an "accidental" git repo at top directory level : make sure you **do not** use `git clean` at that point. It would delete your whole filesystem. Follow choroba's advice and defuse that time bomb.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the `.git` folder in the top of the directory tree.