# How do I undo everything locally with Git?

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm so, so sorry if this is poorly worded. I'll try my best to explain here as I am a very new to programming.

Background: I have been learning python and made my first GUI application using Tkinter just to test and practice skills and logic etc and I wanted to upload to Github.

I made a Github account, downloaded Git and started following a tutorial on YouTube.; "Copying a GitHub Repository to Your Local Computer"[Found here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O72FWNeO-xY&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR1gJWdTjG1J82kNnHHQ89mziuOnIeqbrk50p7DFBHhCN8Xgpxmpp3d5124)

I made the repository on Github. It then instructed me on GitBash. It said to change directory to desktop and the instructions afterwards have basically marked *all my files* with the blue arrows like so (these are just examples:

[Blue arrows over file icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w6xv.png)

As I say it's over all my files. I suspect this means that all these files may(?) be uploaded to the repository on git hub (if I pushed and committed it?) and I *definitely* do not want this. I deleted the repository on the Github end as I just want to start again because I think I've gone wrong as this shouldn't have happened. I have no idea how to undo all of this locally as being new to Git - this is exceptionally un-intuitive for me

I've tried googling however, I suspect and I admit I am likely googling the wrong thing so I'm sorry for my ignorance. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated and I am more then happy to try and clarify, I just may need some pointers. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo git init on a home directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193565/how-to-undo-git-init-on-a-home-directory)

Answer (score 0):

The git repository is the `.git` folder. In your case you should find a .git folder on your desktop. If you are on Windows, be sure to [show hidden folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028316/windows-view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-10). Just delete the .git folder and the whole repository goes away. Easy-peasy rice and cheesey.