# Remove git repo without deleting the contents inside the repo path

Tags: git

Accidently I created a repo using "Git™ Version Control" in the 'Users' folder on c: (deleting the folder isn't an option). I created a new repo to test what happens when you delete a repo and unfortunately everything inside the repo was deleted.
Is there any way to remove the repo and all mentions of it without deleting the files inside?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193565/how-to-undo-git-init-on-a-home-directory Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home

Answer (score 1):

In the normal setup,<sup>1</sup> the *Git repository proper* is itself a sub-directory (or sub-folder) of the top level of your working tree.  For instance if your working tree is named `C:/Users/`, the *repository* is named `C:/Users/.git/`.

To remove the repository, simply *remove the repository*.  The working tree is not touched by a recursive removal of the `.git/` sub-directory, so it remains intact.

(There's a general principal at work here, and this is: your *working tree* is *yours*.  Git will write into it when you tell Git to do so, but it's *yours*.  The Git repository sub-directory is Git's, and Git is touchy about who writes into that, so don't let other programs in there.  Keep Dropbox's grubby little paws off the repository.)

---

<sup>1</sup>You can override this any number of ways, but presuming you didn't explicitly override the normal setup, you have the normal setup.