# Is there a command to undo git flow init?

Tags: git-flow

After `git flow init`, how to remove the git flow model?
How do I remove all related config from the `.git/config` file?

```sh
$ git flow init
```

```sh
# force reset
$ git flow init -f
```

How to remove below content from the `.git/config` file?

```
[gitflow "branch"]
    master = master
    develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
    feature = feature/
    release = release/
    hotfix = hotfix/
    support = support/
    versiontag =
```

Comment: Posible duplicate thread                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212459/is-there-a-command-to-undo-git-init

Comment: @codebreaker, thanks for reply. That thread [#3212459](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212459/is-there-a-command-to-undo-git-init) is about `git int`, not `git flow init`...

Answer (score 159):

You can do what @Peter said from the command line too!

Those commands remove all the sections of the git config file related to gitflow.

```
git config --remove-section "gitflow.path"
git config --remove-section "gitflow.prefix"
git config --remove-section "gitflow.branch"
```

Then you can re-init gitflow as usual.

```
git flow init
```

Comment: Life saviour. Thank you very much

Comment: "gitflow.path" not exists via eclipse Init Gitflow.

Comment: git config --remove-section "gitflow.path" && git config --remove-section "gitflow.prefix" && git config --remove-section "gitflow.branch"

Comment: Ah ah @miva2, I'm glad I was twice useful.

Answer (score 40):

If you removed those sections from your config any reference to git-flow is gone.

There isn't really a need to remove anything though, the git-flow model is just that, it's a model. You can always use standard git commands.

What git-flow adds to your config, only git-flow software will use, not the git itself.

Comment: I think the problem @payliu was running into is that when you run `git flow init` the values you set can't be reset by running `git flow init` a second time. The git flow tools make assumptions about your repo that might not be true when you run `git flow init`. See the issues developers are running into here: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/121