# How can I recover mistakes in git flow init?

Tags: git-flow

I've run `git init` and made a mistake selecting the first branch. Now I want to rerun it to change the settings, but it never asks the first question again.

```
Which branch should be used for bringing forth production releases? 
   - develop

Branch name for production releases: [] develop

Which branch should be used for integration of the "next release"?

Branch name for "next release" development: [develop] ^C
Lymnaea:boxes (develop) $ git flow init

Which branch should be used for integration of the "next release"?

Branch name for "next release" development: [develop]
Production and integration branches should differ.
```

How can I undo the first init run so that I can set the branch to master?

Answer (score 31):

In the end I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480923/is-there-a-command-to-undo-git-flow-init). It's not entirely a duplicate, so I'll leave this here for the next person that cannot find the right keywords.

```
git flow init -f # will force re-initialization
```

If you want to do it manually, you can use `git config -e`.

Comment: You can also edit the file `.git/config` inside your repo, where you’ll those definitions under the `[gitflow "prefix"]` section.