# How to undo misoperation of Reinitialized existing Git repository

Tags: git

I just ran `git init` on an already existing git repo.
The result is **Reinitialized existing Git repository**

How can I undo this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No need - it is quite safe to do. [From the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init):

```
Running git init in an existing repository is safe. 
It will not overwrite things that are already there. 
The primary reason for rerunning git init is to pick up newly added templates.
```

The templates are files such as the sample hooks and example files that are part of git.
If you have updated git since creating the repo and these files have changed, they will not be updated - only new files will be added.
Since none of these files are actually 'active', this should be entirely safe.

Comment: What does **newly added templates** mean?

Comment: Haha! I panicked and started searching even before checking that my repo and commits were intact :)

Comment: @AnmolGupta same here. Strange how I've never made this sort of 'mistake' since I started using git a long time ago. `git log` was able to put me at ease.

Comment: I created a new folder on my desktop to test something and then said open terminal here. It opened to my existing branch I am actually working in and I didn't realize it. Ran git init and nearly pooped my pants when I thought that all of my outgoing changes were stomped. They weren't thankfully. Microsoft drives me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

so that was the first error probably. The error comes from the fact that you haven't really used git yet (haven't tested that scenario sorry).

So to fix, run

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

then

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

and then

```
git remote rm origin
```

and it should be all good. Sorry for the confusing error

Comment: That does not answer the question. And the question already has a correct and accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

To undo the changes made by git init you should delete the git repository. Follow the steps below to make the job done.

**For Linux**

```
rm -rf .git
```

**For Windows**

```
rmdir .git
```

Reference
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-delete-git-repository-created-with-init.html

Comment: This is indeed a good way to get rid of a new Git repository you didn't intend to create. However, the OP is asking how to reverse any negative consequences from running `git init` on an established repo that you *do not* want to delete. (Fortunately, there aren't any negative consequences to speak of.)