# How to remove a git repository from a directory without deleting anything from it?

Tags: git

I accidently initialized my Desktop directory as a local git repository using `git init`, how can I undeclare it to a normal directory without deleting any items in the same.

Comment: Delete the hidden directory ".git". That's it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninitialize git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540577/uninitialize-git-repository)

Answer (score 4):

Git uses a `.git` directory to store the repository history and its meta data - from any directory Git tries to find a `.git` directory above the current directory (by default it stops at mount points) to determine whether the current directory is a working tree.

Just remove the `.git` directory on your desktop (the directory might be hidden as it starts with a dot; you can list it in a console using `ls -la` and remove it using `rm -rf .git`).

Comment: Sorry didnt see your answer coming. Cheers. Really appreciate.

Comment: @rishabh-kanwar Please consider accepting this answer if it helped you. That is the way to say thank you on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In that case go to you command line

change your directory to the directory which you initialized git

Now if you do

```
ls -la
```

You will be able to see **.git** folder which is the main thing to keep track of your git project. To remove this you can use the following command

```
rm -rf .git
```