# VSCode git shows all modified files on computer

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I just started using VSCode and the git version control is showing all modified folders (on my desktop), not just those in my project. I would imagine this is a git root problem, but not sure how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` check this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a git repository from a directory without deleting anything from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48864755/how-to-remove-a-git-repository-from-a-directory-without-deleting-anything-from-i)

Answer (score 4):

You need to check is there any other git is initialized in parent folders of your project. You can check this with `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. Check the path and remove the `.git` folder from there.(If that is unwanted)

Answer (score 0):

One of the parent folders of your project is a git repo. You can find which one by running `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. You probably want to delete the `.git` folder in the folder shown by this command. Before you do so, go to that directory and run `git log` to check if there is any history that you need to keep.