# My vscode shows all the files in my source control

Tags: visual-studio-code

All the files that exist on my local computer are shown in the source control section of vs code,  I tried `ctrl+r` but it still didn't work

[image: Screenshot of my source control]

Comment: Have you, by chance, created a project with its root on C:\?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode git shows all modified files on computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463861/vscode-git-shows-all-modified-files-on-computer)