# command to uninitialize a git repo in Windows

Tags: python, windows, git

What specific syntax needs to be used for a command that works in Windows to uninitialize a Git repo?

In a Windows server, we are encountering the following error when a Python program tries to run shutil.rmtree() on a directory
that contains a git repo.  As you can see below, the error indicates that access to a file within the `.git` subdirectory is
blocked to the `shutil.rmtree()` command.

We have read [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540577/uninitialize-git-repository) which includes suggestions such as to use `rm -rf` in Linux, or to manually delete the `.git` folder in Windows.  We have also read postings that indicate
that `shutil.rmtree()` cannot force destruction as a non-administrator user.

However, the directory was created by the same user running a `git clone` command, so we imagine there must be some `git` command that will purge all the files in `.git`.

Given that our user can `git clone`, we imagine our use could `git uninit`.  So what command do we need to use to approximate `git uninit` and effectively remove `.git` folder and all its contents in Windows without throwing the following error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\to\myapp\setup.py", line 466, in undoConfigure
    shutil.rmtree(config_path)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 739, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 612, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 612, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 612, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 617, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 615, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\path\\to\\callingDir\\.git\\objects\\pack\\pack-71e7a693d5aeef00d1db9bd066122dcd1a96c500.idx'
```

Comment: You're basically asking "how to remove a folder and its contents in Windows"? So `rmdir /s the\offending\folder`? Assuming the git repo is in a state you want to leave it in (i.e. not with some old version currently checked out), you can just `rmdir /s .git`

Comment: @Grismar Typing `rmdir /s .git` results in the response `.git, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y`, which in turn breaks the program.  ...  This manual step has the same problem that manually deleting the folder in Windows Explorer has.  ...  How can you command be modified to NOT require interactivity?  ...  If you can provide a modified version of your command to forcibly delete the .git` folder WITHOUT requiring user input, then that would resolve this OP.  ...

Comment: Pass it `/q` as well and it will quietly assume 'yes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking "how to remove a folder and its contents in Windows"? So rmdir /s the\offending\folder? Assuming the git repo is in a state you want to leave it in (i.e. not with some old version currently checked out), and you are sure you want it removed (no user confirmation), this works:

```
rmdir /s /q .git
```

The `/s` ensures contents are removed as well. And the `/q` assures the operation is quiet (assuming 'y' for confirmation).

In case you're on PowerShell instead of Command Prompt, you can use:

```
Remove-Item ".git" -Force -Recurse
```