# how to undo git init?

Tags: git, git-init

I clicked `git init` in my users folder by mistake, and then everything in my users folder has been turned with a blue question mark.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `As I am totally new to IT`. Please see the guidelines for asking questions.http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: [Is there a command to do undo git init](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3212459/6521116)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a command to undo git init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212459/is-there-a-command-to-undo-git-init)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the Documentation About [git init](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init)

When you run `git init`, a new `.git folder` its created on your project directory with some other subdirectories for objects, `refs/heads`, `refs/tags` , since its a dot file (.git)its hidden by default, so if you are running linux do the following.

```
 cd myFolder
 rm -rf .git
```

If you are running Windows, there are bunch of tutorials to show hidden files, like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/) for example

Comment: ok. but what if that folder already contains a folder with actual project file and and git settings. whether it will affect that too?

Comment: When you run `git init`, you should something like reinitializing, so yes, the `commit`, `adds` should be reset but the `git --config` and other global configurations don't

Comment: Running git init in an existing repository is safe. It will not overwrite things that are already there. The primary reason for rerunning git init is to pick up newly added templates. from [docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html)

Comment: it works, thanks a ton. But it still remains in my libraries folder alone. i will check that too. But i dont find any.git folder in libraries!!!!

Comment: saran nice to hear that, feel free to "accept" or "mark" this answer as accepted i see you are new here check out [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to know how to accept it,

Answer (score 2):

Short and simple

```
rm -rf .git
```

Then, reinitialize as the right user