# Fix a 'git init' issued from the wrong directory without deleting the `.git` folder?

Tags: git, git-init

This is very close to both [Is there a command to undo git init?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3212459) and [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1213430) Unfortunately, the accepted answers do not fit well because I `init`'d my home directory. (I missed a `cd`, and then issued `git init`).

Now, when I try to clone at my home directory, git just hangs and then time's out:

```
$ git clone -v https://gtihub.com/weidai11/cryptopp cryptopp-docs
Cloning into 'cryptopp-docs'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gtihub.com/weidai11/cryptopp/': Connection timed out after 300043 milliseconds
```

The web interface is fine during this timeout period. I can navigate the project, examine commits, etc. I can also clone the same repo from another machine.

I want to avoid blowing out my other configuration information housed in the `~/.git` folder.

How do I fix a `git init` issued from the wrong directory without deleting the `.git` folder?

---

Here's what I am seeing in the home directory:

```
$ ls -Al | grep '.*git*'
drwxr-xr-x   10 jwalton  staff       340 Sep 11 18:51 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 jwalton  staff        83 Jun 16 03:29 .gitconfig
```

And git is showing a bunch of untracked files from the home directory:

```
$ cd ~
$ git status -s | wc -l
91
```

Comment: Have you done more than just `git init`? If you're cloning a repository then you must have committed something somewhere along the line.

Comment: @Whymarrh - I may have; but I don't recall for sure. I was working too late into the night, and my mind was fairly dull (more dull than normal).

Comment: Understood, though as it stands I think this question is a bit unclear. What is it that you're trying to fix and what errors are you seeing? If it's that you're running into an error when cloning a repository, I think that is unrelated to running `git init`.

Comment: If the `.git` folder in your home directory was not supposed to be created there, why can't you just delete it?

Comment: @Whymarrh - OK, thanks. Let's handle the Git de-init without deleting the directory since the init was a mistake. The odd thing is, I can clone from other directories; just not my home directory. I've only noticed it today since today is the first try to clone from the home directory. I fat fingered the init two days ago.

Comment: If you want to "de-init" the Git repository in your home directory, you will eventually need to delete the `.git` subdirectory. You can run `git status` in your home directory to see if there's anything uncommitted (and hopefully everything is). With any luck, `git status` will take a while to report that a lot of files are "untracked" and (closer to the beginning of its output) that you're at the initial commit. If that's the case, you can simply delete the `.git` directory.

Comment: Also, no global state should be stored in that `.git` directory. I think you may be confusing it with your `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: @Whymarrh - yes, that's the underlying concern - losing important information in a configuration file. I have to admit the [`git-confg`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) man pages confused me more that I already am when it comes to git. There are too many `.git` folders, and too many `.gitconfig` files.

Comment: @jww: Oh, but that is easy, actually. `.git` is the directory where there is the configuration of a repository, (file `.git/config` is the most interesting one). The user configuration file is `~/.gitconfig` (or `~/.config/git/config/` if you are an XDG fan). Lastly, the system configuration is `/etc/gitconfig`, but I've never seen that used.