# How can I undo git init?

Tags: git, github, terminal

I have a folder named "code" and in that folder, I have another folder named "resume" inside the code folder. I did "git init" on both folders. How can I undo git init to the parent folder named "code"?

Comment: If I type "undo git init" (question title) into google search, I get [Is there a command to undo git init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212459/is-there-a-command-to-undo-git-init) as first hit, so, a tiny bit more research effort would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you convert a folder to git repository it's creating the `.git` folder under the given folder.

Executing `git init` creates a .git subdirectory in the **current working directory**. If you wish to use a different or subfolder use the `git init <path>` instead

In order to "delete" the git repo form this folder simply remove the `.git` folder

```
# remove the .git folder
rm -rf .git
```

[image]

As you can see above once you remove the `.git` folder its no longer a git repo

Answer (score 2):

You can simply delete the `.git` directory that was created in the "code" folder.

> This command creates an empty Git repository - basically a .git
>   directory with subdirectories for objects, refs/heads, refs/tags, and
>   template files. An initial HEAD file that references the HEAD of the
>   master branch is also created.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init