# Reinitialized existing Git repository when using git init and further?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am a newbie and trying to using Gitbash to push a code to github. When I use the command

`git init`

it shows me the error

`Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/User/User/Desktop/xxx.git`

Then, when I use the command

`git add .` it is ok

when I use the command

`git commit -m "First commit"` it shows me this error

`On branch master Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commits 
Nothing to commit, working tree clean`

And final, when I try to use those command

`git remote add origin https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git 
 git push origin master`

It told me that `error: failed to push some refs to https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git`

I am very confusing because of this error, could you please help me ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Wrong category my friend, please post this one as `git` related, you will get the answer

Comment: You forgot to mention the start: was this a `rails new`, or did you do `git clone`? Your errors seem to suggest this folder was a clone, and thus a `origin/master` was already defined.

Comment: Most outputs are actually errors but infos. The only error occurs on `git push`.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your comments. I solved my problem by undo `git init`, and eveything seemed ok. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212459/is-there-a-command-to-undo-git-init

Answer (score 3):

Please try this to solve the above problem

```
$ rm -rf .git
```

After this command, use:

```
$ git init
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but I fixed it so just use
`$ git add .` 
to add all files from your directory