# I accidentally added C:/ to my svn repository. What can I do? 

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

By mistake i had added `c:/` to our SVN repository.

How can i remove whole `c:` from that repository as i cant delete whole `c:`?

My svn repository is in the `d:/SVN` folder.

Please provide a tested and correct method to resolve the issue. I'm also using Tortoise.

Comment: What's the actual risk? Who has access to the repository? Have you added any private files?

Comment: no i didnt add anythng to anythng...i just added it to svn repo and got stucked in this prob...i only want to hide those icons...

Answer (score 4):

Can you not just revert to a version prior to your checkin, and re-checkin as the head?

Comment: not working...i didnt commit anything till now.its saying use clean up command but cannot clean as it is c:

Comment: svn revert operation is exactly for restoring pending changes in working copy - adding new directories is also kind of pending change

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all .svn folders on C:, except those in the folders you'd wish to keep in repository

Comment: i can only fynd .svn folder in svn as all other folders are showing not saved thats y all having that blue icon

Comment: remove .svn folder on C:/ and see what happens. it's hidden, so you might have to turn on the option for displaying hidden files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the icons, search for folders called `.svn` on drive `C:/` and simply remove them. Since you didn't add anything to the working copy, there should only be one folder, directly under `C:/`.

If you get the message that the `.svn` folder cannot be deleted because it is being used, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init/4312354#4312354) for an advise how to disable the Tortoise refresh temporarily.

If there are more `.svn` directories under `C:/`, remove all of them (as long as you're absolutely sure that these aren't inside a working copy).