# How to delete my repository on Git using command line?

Tags: git, github, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)

I have a test repository on git and I want to delete it using command line. I found that 
    `git rm <file>`    deleted the files within the repository and not the repository itself. Any one can help here?

Comment: You just delete the `.git` hidden folder (not using git commands)

Comment: Although some of the participants in this thread have reported that this is not possible, the following link to a newer thread demonstrates that it is indeed possible:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19327004/2112489  To be fair, this particular thread is a couple of years old, so perhaps this is a newer feature in the API.

Answer (score 18):

For local repo, run

```
rm -r .git
```

You may not delete a repo remotely to github via command line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with *You may not delete a repo remotely to github via command line.* ? We shouldn't delete the repository locally first ? Or on GitHub first ?

Answer (score 3):

try

`rm -r .git`

from the root of the repository.

Comment: I want to delete the repo present on github using commandline

Comment: This isn't possible as linquize pointed out already.