# Remove git-hub repository API

Tags: git, github

I am able to create a repository like this

```
curl -u useraA:token http://mygit/api/v3/user/repos -d '{"name":"foo"}'
```

I am trying to delete the repo but I can't.

I have tried

```
curl -XDELETE -u userA:token http://mygit/api/v3/user/repos/userA/foo
```

but I keep getting a 404 Not Found.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a GitHub repo using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319516/how-to-delete-a-github-repo-using-the-api)

Comment: yes, I followed that. I get a bad credentials. I goto the gui and generate a token which has FULL privledges. For whatever reason I keep getting Bad credentials. In addition, I tried it with passing -H 'Authorization: xxxxxx' (where xxxx is the token hash)

Comment: @NinjaGaiden did you try only with `-H 'Authorization: xxxxxx'` (without `-u user:token` used at the same time)?

Comment: yes, I tried that also. Same.