# can you delete a repo via pygithub?

Tags: python-3.x, github, pygithub

Can you delete a repo using pygithub?
For example, as shown in [this](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Repository.html#delete-a-file-in-the-repository) example, you can delete a file like so:

```
repo = g.get_repo("userName/repoName")
contents = repo.get_contents("filename.txt", ref="test")
repo.delete_file(contents.path, "remove test", contents.sha, branch="test")
```

Is there something analogous for deleting entire repos? If not, how can one do this via the github API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a GitHub repo using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319516/how-to-delete-a-github-repo-using-the-api)

Comment: Ideally I would like to use the python library pygithub, however if this is not possible then yes, this would suffice. If you could demonstrate that this is not possible using pygithub then I'll accept this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pygithub documentation](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html#github.Repository.Repository.delete) does include a `delete()` method, which calls the exact [GitHub repo DELETE API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#delete-a-repository) `delete /repos/{owner}/{repo}`

So it should be possible to call that method, as in [`PyGithub/PyGithub` `tests/Repository.py`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/3ec145f2219256a0fec5ed3395eec5dfbc74609c/tests/Repository.py#L158-L160)

```py
g=Github('token')
repo = self.g.get_user().get_repo("TestPyGithub")
repo.delete()
```

Comment: Thanks, as an additin `g=Github('token')

Comment: @Timo Good point, thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Do you know why in linux there is my vscode workspace folder named with a 13 digit number: `/home/tk/.config/Code/Workspaces/1619293380488`. New question?

Comment: @Timo that would be a new question indeed (while I am looking into it). Do mention your vscode version.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm @VonC, it works.

Notice that the token must be enabled to delete a repo (tick the delete_repo box when creating the token on GitHub portal)