# how to delete a repo in github using gitbash commands?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a repository in Github which created and pushed using GitBash commands locally. Here, I want to delete that repo using the same method in other words, how to delete that repo using GitBash command?

I know the repo can be remove using user interface of Github but It's not what i'm looking for.

Thank You :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319516/how-to-delete-a-github-repo-using-the-api

Answer (score 1):

Git commands only support establishing and manipulating repositories. You cannot delete a repository via git commands.

A git repository on your remote server is simply a folder, usually a `bare` repository that holds the contents of the `.git` folder that you know from your local repositories. If you can ssh to your remote you can simply delete the repository folder.

```
rm -rf myrepository/
```

Answer (score -1):

You can delete the repository from your Github account. The path is project-settings-delete(on the bottom).

Comment: The question is specifically asking: "How to delete repo.. using gitbash commands" and says "I know the repo can be remove using user interface"