# Delete repository on github using ubuntu command terminal

Tags: ubuntu, github, command-line

I have a repository named `my_wor`k on GitHub. In that repository I have 4 files. I want to know if I can directly delete the `my_work` folder from command terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for local repo:

```
rm -r .git
```

from the root of the repository.

other links that can help you:
[How to delete my repository on Git using command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243619/how-to-delete-my-repository-on-git-using-command-line)

[How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)