# Git root - accidentally created a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

Can somebody tell me how to get back to my main Git root directory?  My command prompt was pointing to

```
c:/Sites
```

but now, the command prompt is pointing to:

```
c/Sites (new_branch)
```

Not sure how I got there but I suspect that I must have accidentally created a new branch.  I tried "git branch" but returned no results.  Also tried "git checkout master" but got an error: "pathspec master did not match any file(s) known to git."

I'm on windows 7.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you confusing directories (in your filesystem) with Git branches? Are you on Windows? Do you mean `C:\Sites` rather than `C:/Sites`? What exactly do you mean by "I'm stuck in `c/Sites (new_branch)`; what command produced that output?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` output?

Comment: Indeed, this question needs a lot of editing for clarity.

Comment: Keith: I'm using windows so yes, the path is c:/Sites.  The prompt is defaulting to "c/Sites (new_branch)" whereas before the prompt was simply my root path, "c/Sites"

Comment: Ruslan: git branch -a doesn't list anything.  I typed it in and simply get a new command prompt.  No branches are listed.

Comment: did you already commit something in this repo? If not, delete the `.git` folder and re-create the repo with `git init`. It's a bit confusing that `git branch` shows absolutely nothing, so I assume you did something completely wrong and it would be the best to re-init the repo. If you're unsure whether you did anything in the repo, ask `git log` to give you the list of commits you already did. Or open `gitk` in your repo. If there are no commits, simply re-init (http://stackoverflow.com/q/1213430/520162)

Comment: aruisdante - your comments need to add more value, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you do not see anything with ls -l .git/refs/heads , it implies that you no longer have master branch (may be you deleted your master branch unknowingly as you said above you weren't sure when you accidentally created your branch.

To go back to your original master branch, check your git log for when you created  the new branch. once you obtain the commit sha , recreate you master branch with "git checkout -b master ". This will take you to your default prompt.

Comment: Thanks, Miyurz.  That did the trick!  Have no idea what happened but I'm good now!

Answer (score 1):

This means that your directory is now tracked by Git. Since you have that error try to do:

```
git checkout new_branch
```

Alternatevely

```
git checkout -b master
```

Comment: Thanks, Koninos.  Worked perfectly!  Miyurz provided the same solution but he and I went back and forth a few times so I accepted his answer.  Still, thanks for the multiple solutions!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
git checkout master
```

to go back to master..

Comment: I already tried that but get the following error message:  "pathspec master did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: 0 down vote
 

What does ls -l .git/refs/heads show ?

Comment: Miyurz - says: total 0