# how can I delete 2 Github repositories made 4 years ago

Tags: netbeans, github

My IDE is Netbeans and I am trying to remove 2 forks I made 4 years ago.
[image: old repositories]

The forks I want to delete are imagej and fiji. I used a clone from inside Netbeans and I got the code from 4 years ago. I tried to delete using

[fully delete repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)

I picked up the fiji folder on my local machine as a result of the Netbeans clone. According to the reference this is what I want to delete. There was a .git directory both in the parent directory on my disk and another .git directory inside the fiji folder. This apparently came from the Netbeans clone. I could see that I wouldn't get very far trying to delete the fiji folder from inside the same folder.

Finally I got fed up and deleted the fiji folder on my machine as well as the .git directory in the parent directory. Then I did a git init to create a new .git and set my user name and email.

I could clone again fiji to get a copy on my local disk. I'm not really interested in getting 4 year old information again. What I want to do is get my hands on the github repositories and delete them so that I can fork them again. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely?rq=1 This looks promising. Just I getfatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: It seems to almost work  ilan@ilan-main:~/ilan/Java/fijiSource$ git push origin --delete fijiUsername for 'https://github.com': ilan
Password for 'https://ilan@github.com': 
error: unable to delete 'fiji': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ilan/fiji.git'

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at
https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository

It works as expected.
Thanks,
Ilan