# Where are Github files/references in a project under Github source control?

Tags: git, github, tfs

Let me explain my situation. I had an ASP.NET project

```
packages
   EntityFramework6.1.1
   .
   .
MyProject
   App_Data
   .
   .
MyProject.sln
```

under source control in GitHub. I copied those project files onto another machine. Now I want to put that project on the other machine under source control in TFS. The problem is that somehow Visual Studio knows/thinks the project is under source control in GitHub and so it doesn't let me add it to TFS (the option for TFS that is there when you right-click the solution is not there). Yet, I've looked through the source files and can't find any references to GitHub. Where would they be? I want to get rid of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)

Comment: Just to nitpick a bit. Github is a Git host. You want to remove the Git repository. There are other Git hosts than Github. In fact Git doesn't even need a host, it's decentralized.

Comment: @Subpar Did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 6):

After you copy it (the files) to a new location delete the `.git` Directory.  It's hidden so make sure you can see hidden files and folders in folder options