# Android Studio doesn't push all files in Github

Tags: git, android-studio

I am pushing my project to github,but the java files are not there. However,I can see the res folder and its files...The proceedure I followed was.

VCS-->Enable Version Control->Git.

And then

VCS-->Import into version control-->Share project on Github.

Any ideas? I am new to github.

To have a better idea of my problem please check [this](https://github.com/theo82/RegistrationandLogin) link. You will notice what files are missing

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you added the files missing to be handled by Git. (Select them, right click Git -> Add OR VCS -> Git -> Add)

Comment: Nothings happens:(. The files inside the package don't have red or green colors,which means that they are already pushed!

Comment: Anyway,how do delete the project from the repository? I mean to disconnect the project in Android Studio from Git.

Comment: To delete the repo Just remove .git dir inside the root where you created the repo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init

Comment: Ok I fixed it. Thanks. :)

Comment: is this a bug? .gitignore ignores my .java files