# What happens if I remove the .git directory from a project under GIT? Is it a good way to "ungit" my project?

Tags: java, git, version-control

maybe it could be a trivial question (I am not so into GIT).

I have a Java project that is synchronized with my remote GIT repository. So into my project I have the **.git** directory. My Java project still works fine?

If I want momentarily "ungit" my project, can I remove the **.git** directory from my project? Then adding it again to my project it will again under GIT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)

Comment: Yes. The folder `.git` is the core of a git repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will ungit your project. But make sure that the current branch is the code you want