# How to delete local git init project

Tags: git

I've created a repository by following the tutorial on git

git init project1
cd project1

now i wanted to delete this project1 folder but i cannot delete it.
people say I need to delete the hidden .git folder, but theres no such thing exist

Comment: It's a hidden file. `rm -rf .git ` shall remove any git-related info about such project.

Comment: What os do you use? It's hidden by default

Comment: doesnt work, the entire folder is empty, shows hidden files its empty. but I cannot delete the folder like i lost authority to it, im using windows 7

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init. If yes, can you type **git status** to see if it's still a git repository

Comment: yes already tried that, I restarted my computer and I were able to delete it

Comment: You can open your `git bash` in project's directory and can use `rm -rf .git` command.

Answer (score 0):

close all git bash , git gui or cmd .
and from the windows explorer delete the folder