# Remove complete my GIT files at company leave?

Tags: git

I decide to move on in my life and change company. I want to remove all my GIT repositories ( private one - and probably backup them ) from company git server. I know that best way is probably to delete folder where my files are stored. But i want to do clean way out.

Mostly of this repositories are my own private ( since i have good relationship with my boss - he allowed me to use company git server for my private projects which aren't in conflict with company primary projects ( most of them are my PHP/mySQL tests and apps while i'm C# dev ).

I must admit at start that i don't have any experience with git ( mostly i used svn ) except push pull commit.

thanks in advance.

Sile

Comment: according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init git keeps all of its files in the .git directory. So when you are deleting your project directories they should be gone as well. The other answer in the post where the user talks about rm -rf .git, could also be used.

Comment: This is really bad, the company might actually legally own that code now, I'm not sure why you did this.

Comment: I do agree with @snb. For future, You should use services like github or bitbucket, both of which have options for private repositories (github is paid, bitbucket is free to certain extent).

Answer (score 0):

*I would suggest changing your question so it does not contain your job issues but only the technical question - my answer is in that vein. Ethical questions would be better suited for The Workplace.*

Git is pretty simple regarding its storage. Client-side you have your working directory including the single `.git` subdirectory. Remove all that.

Server-side it depends on which software is running on the server. If it is a simple `ssh` login that you use in "git over ssh" mode, then you will find a so-called "bare" repository on the server. This is the same as the `.git` you know on your client, only that there are no working files checked out, and the `.git` is not there either, but the files are directly in the top level server directory. Delete that, and it's done.

If you run something like `gitolite` etc. on the server, please edit your question to make that clear.