# Changing GitHub Account Swift Project

Tags: github

I would like to change a swift project from one GitHub account to another account. I want to commit the project to another account but I get an error - I assume I need to remove the .git file from the project but the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init) is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why do that?? No, all you have to do is define the new repo, push to it, then remove the other one. Each Git repo is on a local machine. That repository can be synced with one or more remote repositories. Right now, you probably have GitHub (account 1) setup as origin (a remote). What I would do is:

1. rename origin to oldrepo or something
2. create origin with the new url
3. push to it

Then you can remove the old one.

To edit your remotes, you can either do commands:

`git remote remove origin, get remote add origin <newUrl>`

or you can edit the .git/config file with an editor.

[Git: Working with Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Comment: I am getting the error "failed to add file xxx to index." What I did was stupid but this isn't a huge project - but I deleted the repository from my original account and now I am no longer able to commit under the new/old account

Comment: In that case I would erase .git and then do git init, add all the files, commit, and then add the remote again pointing to the new repo. NEVER destroy history though.. :)