# How do I push a project to GitHub that contains a create-react-app subfolder?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm trying to push my whole directory to GitHub but having some problems as `create-react-app` automatically git inits. And if I initialise git in my main directory (app),  I'll have one repo in another. How would I approach this? I've only been working with git for a few months so I only really understand the basics.

Thanks in advance.

Folder structure:

```
- app
  - server
  - client (create-react-app)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since git in `create-react-app` was automatically initialized, I would assume you do not need anything that was generated. Simply delete `.git` directory: [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)

`.gitignore` which was automatically generated will not be deleted as it is not contained in `.git` directory.

After that is done, initialize a new git repo where you want. 
Just in case, before you start deleting, copy everything elsewhere to have a backup.

Comment: Hey Luka, thank you for the comment, your solution worked for me.