# GitHub Arrow on Folder Can't Open

Tags: github

[image: This is an image of my GitHub page]

I am trying to push multiple folders onto GitHub. However after pushing the local repository to GitHub, I can't open the folder "React_Projects" folder. There is an arrow on the folder instead and I can't click on it.

Why can't I open the folder and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them

Answer (score 3):

That icon is to indicate a git submodule, which has a link to the commit of another git version-controlled project/repository. You can read more about git submodules [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

You can also go to that folder and go to view -> hidden items and click it. check if you see a .git hidden folder. if you do just delete it and push again. that should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by deleting .git folder inside subfolders (Hidden files and folders). You should have only one .git in the root folder.

I used [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init) to know how I can delete a .git folder from my subfolders of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open visual studio code in your project folder.
Step 2: Then go to File > Prefernces > settings > Text Editor > Files
Step 3: Scroll down your cursor till "Exclude" .There Delete .git Item
Step 4: Now you can see the hidden .git file in your folder structure. Delete it from there.  After that it will work