# How do I delete every change to my local git repository?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I first opened VSCode and entered the VCS tab, I saw over 5000 changes, so much that VSCode won't show me the real number.

Is there a way to delete all of these changes, since I don't use my local git (I only use git via IDEs)?

I've already tried `git reset --hard`, `git clean -fd`, and more, but nothing works.

Comment: Is there a possibility that you are dealing with an EOL-format problem? That might make all your files change without you doing anything (and it's something you should get rid of before moving a single finger).

Comment: I genuinely don't know (I'm a beginner at this stuff). Is there a way to tell?

Comment: Well.... there's an easy one: all those files, did you really change them? Another one is: _the files look as gone completely and replaced with the same content if you run `git diff` _? If the answer is no and yes (in that order), then it's an EOL format change because of your git configuration.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't really see a point in fixing it if I'm not even using the repository, but anyway - it seems like you're right.

Comment: your problem is a .git directory somewhere in the directory path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)