# Fixing newbie git mistake

Tags: git

I'm setting up git for the first time and I seem to have made my entire user folder on my hard drive a git repository, which means that it's constantly tracking all files. Can anyone advise on the best way to fix this?

Comment: It depends on which outcome you want. The simplest fix would be to remove the .git folder from where you created your repository. Obviously, this will delete any history of any files which you have already chosen to commit. You will have to tell us more about what you expect the end result to be before a solid answer can be given.

Comment: Great, thanks! I was just trying to set up git for the first time and definitely didn't want to create a repository that is essentially my whole computer. So, I'd like to be able to get rid of that repository, so it isn't tracking 5,000 files.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove .git hidden folder that should be on directory root path. Also you can check here [How to fully delete a git repository created with init?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213430/how-to-fully-delete-a-git-repository-created-with-init)