Accidentally tracked everything on my laptop with git
Somehow I ended up with all my desktop files queued as changes to commit to Github any project I create. It happened to an old one, so I made a new project, but I still have 1K+ changes to commit (my desktop). If I try to "discard changes" I get an error that says "Are you sure you want to DELETE file.name? this is IRREVERSIBLE! The file wil be FOREVER LOST if you proceed." and it means it, I tested a file I don't care about and it is indeed deleted.

You have created a repo at too high of a level. Maybe in the desktop itself, or on a folder that the desktop folder is in. You should delete the repo and re-create it in the proper location (in the project folder, usually, or at least in a folder that contains project folders - the things you want to track with git). This is easiest, as long as you don't mind "starting over" from the current state of your source code files.

Don't delete your files.  But you can remove the .git folder of a repo that was created unintentionally and all your files will remain in their current state.  Sounds like you somehow may have done a git init while you were in your desktop folder.  Note that the .git folder is hidden by default.  See How to fully delete a git repository created with init?.

Specifically, this Answer has instructions that are applicable to a Mac.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213446/139985.

You know, now I'm realizing I'm not sure what repo it would be pushing to because I just created a new next.js app on my machine that wasn't connected to a Github repo. However, I followed the steps to unhide the .git file and delete and it seems to have resolved the problem. Any ideas where it may have committed my "changes" to had I done that?

Please, gurus, can we agree never to suggest to a newcomer to remove a .git directory? Only rename it? Pretty please? People might think removing stuff is a good idea, and if things go south they are left without any means to recover.

You have to remove .git folder. Then tracking of changes will disappear but not files. After that you have to run git init in project folder.

As many others have said, your git repository is at too high level. You should move the repository to a sub-directory.
As you have not commit yet, it means things or to say changes have not go into "repository area", they are still staying in "staging area".

So you could

do git clone to clone the repository area to somewhere else to keep the old commits and discard all unwanted files in staging area.
remove the old .git directory.

For example, if your old git repository is at /tmp/blah, you want to put the repository to /tmp/blah/work_dir, you could do this:
mkdir work_dir
cd work_dir
git clone /tmp/blah
cd blah
git status

If everything is OK, you could rename the .git at /tmp/blah to stop git tracking files. And new .git is at /tmp/blah/work_dir/blah.

git clean --force will remove them from being tracked if for some reason you want your repo in that folder.
Or just remove the .git folder as mentioned by others.

That may delete all the files in their home directory or wherever they accidentally created the repository. Don't use git clean --force if you don't know what you're doing!

It won't delete any files, it removes them from the working tree which is the index for git, not from the file system

"remove from working tree" == "delete from file system". The working tree and the index are distinct.

Please, never suggest to a newcomer to remove stuff. Only rename. And git clean --force is the dagger that kills everything. If you must, suggest git clean -n to find out what would be removed and add "to do it for real, look it up in the manual", so they learn about the sharp edges.
